# Delete a file inside a folder in Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My wish is very simple and basic. However, I can't find any working/clear answer for it :D

I want to know how to delete a file inside a folder in Google Cloud storage.

If let's say I have a bucket name of `xxxx.appspot.com` and I have a folder inside called `images` and I have an image inside this folder (E.g. `123.jpg`) which I want to delete.

This is the code I wrote, however it didn't delete it:

```
String bucketName = "xxxx.appspot.com";
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();                   
gcsService.delete(new GcsFilename(bucketName,"images/123.jpg"));
```

Did I miss anything?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find some code samples [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects). In short, what you want to achieve can be done in Java using a couple of lines of code, given that you have the right permissions:

```
BlobId b = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
boolean deleted = storage.delete(b);
```

Comment: yeah I know, but what blob name should look like ?

Comment: I think it should be something like: `String blobName = "images/123.jpg"`

Comment: when I don this it give me this Exception                     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
 at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
 at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:75)
 at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:53)
 at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.delete(StorageImpl.java:384)
 at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.delete(StorageImpl.java:397)

Comment: are you importing the right library? `import com.google.cloud.storage.*`

Comment: yup Im sure and here is my code snipped                                           Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();       BlobId bId = BlobId.of("xxxx.appspot.com", "images/123.jpg");          storage.delete(bId)

Comment: Which is the exact method for what it is prompting the `NoSuchMethodError`? Do you get any information on the script line or the method that is failing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160623/discussion-between-tamer-saleh-and-yandrak3).

Comment: @TamerSaleh I know it's been ages you worked on it but I'm facing same error while deleting an object. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer as of 2022 is the following:

```java
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

public class DeleteObject {
    public static void deleteObject(String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName) {
        // The ID of your GCP project
        // String projectId = "your-project-id";

        // The ID of your GCS bucket
        // String bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name";

        // The ID of your GCS object
        // String objectName = "your-object-name";

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        storage.delete(bucketName, objectName);

        System.out.println("Object " + objectName + " was deleted from " + bucketName);
    }
}
```

Example taken from this [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects)

Comment: I'm getting same error Tamer was facing. no such method error.